# Check similarity of table/csv of Product Names

Tags: similarity, fuzzy-logic, text-filter

We've got a list of approximately 18,000 product names (they're from 80-90 sources, so quite a few that are similar but not duplicates - these were picked as DISTINCT from a table) unfortunately there are different ways of expressing these names. We have to try and normalize the dataset so we present our users with more meaningful names.

For example, a list like this:

```
Canon EOS 5D Mark III
Canon EOS 5D mk III
Canon EOS 5DMK3
Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM Lens
Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM Telephoto Zoom Lens
Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS USM Lens
Canon EF 70-200mm f/4L USM Lens
```

I'd like to be able to assess those strings and collapse them into something like this:

```
Canon EOS 5D Mark III
Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM 
Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS USM Lens
Canon EF 70-200mm f/4L USM Lens
```

But I'd like to know how similar two strings are to be able to determine this. I do realise that the F2.8 IS II and IS USM may be a bit hard, but thought I'd throw it in.

The real product names are far less exciting (they're parts for the farm equipment we stock).

We also store these names in a Postgres (9.5) database table. Examples i've seen compare two lists, but we don't have a master product list to do that unfortunately.

Comment: If you do not have a master product list, do you have a public site which users search for your products on? You need some sort of signal to distinguish duplicates. Otherwise you will have to encode this information yourself with a model like a CRF. For more information, see [this tutorial](https://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~getoor/Tutorials/ER_VLDB2012.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a master list to go by and currently we're not keeping tabs of our search queries. It's an ancient Delphi 5 App that runs queries hitting a webservice. I think the original was in TurboPascal, so this new work is to put this behind an engine like Solr or ElasticSearch. That tutorial does resonate with me, so I'm reading through it now! Thanks very much!

Comment: I would recommend keeping track of search queries so you can correlate query strings with products (click throughs). So be sure to keep track of timestamps too. Welcome to DataScience.SE and good luck!

Comment: Some ideas here: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-tutorial-fuzzy-name-matching-algorithms-7a6f43322cc5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is known as detection of near-duplicate documents, i.e. you have strings that are similar but not exact duplicate. The most common approaches are using [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) and [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). You could check this [page](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ml/publications/area/81/record_linkage_and_duplicate_detection/abstracts/) for more information

First you have to convert your strings to a vector of features, this features could be [tf-idf vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) of all the tokens (words) that appear in the database, could also be a vector of [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). For a discussion of semantic and syntactic features you can look [here](http://www2013.org/proceedings/p1273.pdf).

Finally you would have to check the similarity of every pair of documents, in your case 18000. The brute force approach is O(n^2), so this could be unfeasible. A common technique to deal with this issue is to use fingerprinting (hashing) together with Locality Sensitive Hashing (LSH).

You can find an introduction and a general discussion of the whole topic in Chapter 3 of [Mining Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf)

Comment: Thanks alot, I will read through those materials. They look very similar (ha!) to what we're trying to solve. You're all awesome!